# How to write your own "functional API" like in keras?

Tags: python, keras, signal-processing

Keras has a functional API where you put in the singals behind the function call like:

```
x = Input(shape=(782))
x = Dense(1024)(x)
x = Dense(1024)(x)
```

I wanted to create my own signal processing library with the same syntax and I could not find anything (maybe because there is a special word for this method that I could not find).

So assuming a simple example like:

```
def add(w)(x):
    """
        w is the constant, x is the input signal
    """
    
    return w+x

x = np.random.randint(0,255,shape=(100,100,3))
x = add(5)(x)
x = add(5)(x)
```

How would I need to write the add function to have this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create classes and define the [built-in `__call__` method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__call__-in-python/) in them. So eg. you would create an "Add" class where the constructor takes `w` argument, and also a `__call__(x)` method inside this class. Check the Dense layer implementation for more: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1192

Example:

```
class Add:
    def __init__(self, w):
        self.w = w
    
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.w + x

x = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(100,100,3))
x = Add(5)(x)
x = Add(5)(x)
```